# How to find the share of clients who "outflow" every month? (SQLite or Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite, datetime, count

The CLIENTS table contains a monthly snapshot of the bank's clients,
who have made any transactions in the given month. Attributes: report_month
and client_id. We assume that the client "outflow" from the bank in month N, if in month N
it is active (present in the CLIENTS table) and inactive in months N + 1, N + 2, N + 3.

How to find the share of clients who "outflow" every month?

Table looks like:

```
report_month   client_id
2020-01-01     0023
2020-03-01     0125
```

...

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions and a window frame. In standard SQL, this would look like:

```
select report_month, sum(case when cnt = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as outflow
from (
    select t.*,
        count(*) over(
            partition by client_id 
            order by report_month
            range between interval '1' month following and interval '3' month following
        ) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
group by report_month
```

This assumes that `report_month` is of a date-like datatype, and that each customer has 0 or 1 record per `report_month`. If a customer may appear more than once in a month, you would change the outer conditional `sum()` to:

```
count(distinct case when cnt = 0 then client_id end) as outflow
```

---

In SQLite, that has poor date arithmetics support, it is a bit more complicated. If you can live with an approximation of month periods, you could do something like this:

```
select report_month, sum(case when cnt = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as outflow
from (
    select t.*,
        count(*) over(
            partition by client_id 
            order by julianday(report_month)
            range between 28 following and 92 following
        ) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
group by report_month
```

Comment: Yes, report_month is date and customer appear once. But in this code I get the following error: near "'1'": syntax error. I try it in sqlite

Comment: @GreenMr: which version of SQLite are you running? The above code would happily run on Oracle, which you also tagged and mentionned in your question.

Comment: SQLite 3.29. Sorry for that, I thought they have the same functions =(

Comment: @GreenMr: this is why you should always only tag one database, not more... See my edit for an alternative for SQLite.

Comment: sorry for that question but what means 28 and 92 in your code for sqlite? julianday format data to int like that 2458239.5

Comment: @GreenMr: in Julian days `1`is one day, so this means from 28 to 92 days after the date on the current row.